# Convert PHP object to JSON format problem with single item arrays

Tags: php, json, laravel, datatable, vuetify.js

Im creating a service that displays some information in a Vuetify datatable. 
The problem is that when I get an answer from the server that's using json_encode. The one of the values will sometimes be a single value which will be translated into an object and not an array. As far as my knowledge goes, using vuetify requires it to be an array to display it correctly.

I Already tried to explicitly tell the object that it's an array.

```
[
 {
 "values": "something",
  "Items": {
    "item" : [{ "Iteminfo": "Item1" },
            { "Iteminfo": "Item2"}
             ]
   }
 }
]

///////// result with single Object
[
 {
 "values": "something",
  "Items": {
    "item" : { "Iteminfo": "Item1"}
  }
 }
]
```

//// Vuetify

```html
     <v-data-table
          :headers="headers"
          :items="orders"
          :expand="expand"
          :dark="false"
          item-key="Name"
        >
          <template v-slot:items="props">
            <tr @click="props.expanded = !props.expanded">
               <td>Order: {{ props.item.Ordernumber }} , Klantnaam:  {{               
           props.item.Name }}
           </td>  

            </tr>
          </template>
          <template v-slot:expand="props">
            <v-card flat>   
              <v-card-text>
        <table>
         <tr>
          <th>Artikelnummer</th>
         </tr>                  
         <tr v-for="item in props.item.Items.item">
          <td>{{ item.Article }}</td>
         </tr> 
        </table>
       </v-card-text>
      </v-card>
     </template>
    </v-data-table>

///For getting the information
<script>

    export default{        

      data () {
    return {

      filiaalnummer: '',
      expand: false,
      headers: [
        {
          text: 'Orders',
          align: 'left',
          sortable: false,
          value: 'name'
        },    

      ],
      orders: [],

    }
  },  
      methods: {

           getOrders : function(){
               console.log(this.filiaalnummer);
            axios.get('/orders/getOrders/'+this.filiaalnummer)
            .then(response => this.orders =response.data)
            .catch(error => console.log(error.response.data));
        },    

      }

    }

  </script>
```

```
Laravel Server Side 
return json_encode($arrayOfObjectsContainingTheItems);
```

To get the items inside of the Object I need them to be inside an array. And when a single object is presented it will encode to an object aswell, which results in Vuetify trying to read al de individual properties of that object as Items. 
Can I explicityly tell PHP that it needs to be an array? Or can I do something in Vuetify to read the object nonetheless?

Comment: Where are you running `json_encode` can you share the code?

Comment: I updated The Post to include the encode and the request

Comment: *I already tried to explicitly tell the object that it's an array.*, where?

Comment: Server Side  inside the PHP Object
```
$this->item = array($ItemsWhichSometimesCanBeASingleObject);
```
Not sure if it's a good way of typing it, Seems like the json_encode still sees it as an Object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it using the JsonSerializable interface

```
    public function jsonSerialize() {
      if(is_array($this->item)){
        return $this->item;
      }else{
        return array($this->item);
      }
```